# What is safest distance for a dormant black hole?

Tags: physics, orbital-mechanics, black-holes

Would it be safe for humanity if instead of Proxima Centauri being a red dwarf, it was a stellar mass black hole?

**Edit**:

Narrowed the question

Comment: Try to read more about black holes. What is dormant black hole for you? And don't forget mass is a mass is a mass. No matter if it's a star, tight cluster, black hole, planet - if mass is the same, effect on the neighborhood is the same.

Comment: Also, see http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/11805/809

Comment: Hi, platypus. Can you explain what you mean by a "dormant black hole"?

Comment: @HDE226868 Black hole where there's no matter falling in it to feed it. http://futurism.com/what-does-it-mean-when-a-black-hole-is-dormant-2/

Comment: How-would-X-affect-humanity questions are inherently very broad and, as such, ill-suited to the Stack Exchange format. I would suggest limiting your question to the one or two topics you're most interested in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A stellar mass black hole would have the same effect as a star at that distance; essentially negligible. Astronomers would have an interesting time working out the nature of the object perturbing the orbits of Alpha Centauri A and B once their instruments were sensitive enough to take the required measurements, but the idea of a black hole was actually worked out in the 1700's once the speed of light was accurately determined, so astronomers could theorize about the "dark star" at Alpha Centarui C if they were still using Newtonian physics.

As for part 2 of your question, the Solar System does indeed orbit around a Black Hole; the supermassive one at the heart of the Milky Way galaxy. Our rotation around the galaxy haas a period of @ 250 million years, and if we were a lot closer, the solar system would be encountering unpleasant effects quite frequently (i.e. passing through interstellar gas clouds, possible near encounters with other stars, rogue planets, higher background radiation etc.).

[image]

Comment: Note also that a steller mass BH is a lot more massive than the red dwarf. While it's an open question as to whether Proxima is bound to Alpha Centauri, a BH in the same position would indeed affect the position of the AB pair.